# Add tag parameter to category.php

Tags: categories, functions

I want to give users the ability to refine their results in the category section. Like if the user is in the "car" category section in there he can then refine the "search" by color, number of wheels, etc tags. Is this possible without messing up all the pagination logic, etc of the category.php page? Sort of like turning the category.php into a search page. Also not looking for sub categories but rather the ability to add multiple tags to refine the results.

Answer (score -2):

This is an old plugin, but I think you will get idea from [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tdo-tag-fixes/)

Similar thing is possible with this plugin, you will find more details in plugin description.

Alternatively you can use "pre_get_posts" action in your theme's functions.php file to call only on category archive page using below code. Below code will add filter on the category.php page to fetch posts with tag 'red'.

```
function tag_filter_category( $query ) {
if ( is_category() ) {
   $query->set( 'tag', 'red' ); // to fetch posts with tag red (color)
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'tag_filter_category' );
```

Comment: More information on [wordpress site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

and other [helpful tutorial](http://presscustomizr.com/snippet/three-techniques-to-alter-the-query-in-wordpress/)